# How to validate a username from database using bootstrap validator in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I want to validate a username from database using bootstrap validator in asp.net.
This is some code i tried but not working...
When i put remote, the username field is always invalid.
Is this correct way to do so?

```
username: {
                    validators: {                                                        
                        remote: {
                         url: '/Registration.aspx/CheckUsername',
                         type:'POST',
                         data: '{user: "' + $("#<%=username.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
                            message: 'The username is not available.',

                        },
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'Please fill in your username.'
                        }
                    }
                },
```

----backend

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string CheckUsername(string user)
    {
        string retval = "";
        SqlConnection bbmsConn;
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        bbmsConn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        bbmsConn.Open();


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select username from Accounts where username=@username", bbmsConn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            retval = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            retval = "false";
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: [Have you tried this?](http://formvalidation.io/examples/integrating-asp-net/)

Comment: yes, i just dont know how to validate the username with database...

Comment: Have you tried the code locally?

Comment: yes,i tried....

Comment: Doesn't it work locally?

Comment: what you mean by locally? without database validation?

Comment: locally means by running your project within visual studio and local database which resides on your machine.

Comment: Oh, not working also for this..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your whole code which creates issue but may be this part needs correction,
Change this:

```
data: '{user: "' + $("#<%=username.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
```

With this:

```
data: '{user: "' +$("#<%=userName.ClientID%>").val()+ '" }',
```

This will get you the value within userName `textBox`.

Comment: Create a test code, a button and a text box, get textBox value on button click with jquery, see if it works or not in your page.

Comment: Other work fine, just i cant check username with existence database, i dont know what is the problem..